# WatchOS5 - how to debug an apple watch app?

Tags: debugging, crash, ios12, watchos-5

I'm brand new to watchOS development - have my first app and extension. I have the following questions:

- **Are breakpoints available for watch OS extensions and apps?** I set them, but they don't seem to trigger
- Does the app fail to appear on the watch if there's a fatal crash during launch? It seems when I make a mistake, the app simply fails to install and I get almost no info in console and no stack trace of any kind.

**How do I debug a WatchOS5 app is there some option I need to enable on device or XCode?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select watch complication or extension from the list of schemes in the run menu and run the app on watch and device. I was running the test app only.

The bad news is that the process times out on my old Macbook air when trying to run on device. And the watch Simulator is terribly slow, working at about 2 FPS.

[image]